# Do different cars have different performance characteristics?

Tags: sarpbc

After completing a series of single player mini-games in [Supersonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle-Cars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_Acrobatic_Rocket-Powered_Battle-Cars), you are given more cars to choose to drive.

Do the various cars perform differently, or do they all behave the same way and only have visual (aesthetic) differences? I don't see anything in the interface to suggest that they are unique, but why would it progressively open up more cars as you complete the mini-games, if they don't matter to the game play?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_Acrobatic_Rocket-Powered_Battle-Cars#Cars) states that they aren't supposed to have unique stats, but do "behave slightly different." Has anyone figured out what that difference is, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post by a Psyonix mod in their SARPBC forum:

http://psyonix.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7462&sid=8d0d31b2a60415376b9850981e50185e#p159854

> Since it has long been debated, here are the mass of each car. The mass is derived from the physics box that is used as the collision for each car. The box is in slightly different places, and possibly at slightly different angles due to the suspension of each car. This difference is what makes the cars seem different, even though the forces applied to each of them is the same. We never tried to get them to be exact, only close enough. **The mass will affect the steering, air handling, acceleration, and jump heights of each vehicle. The higher the mass, the less each of these forces will affect the car. Top speeds are the same because they are clamped after the velocity is calculated, but how long it takes to get there will vary slightly with the acceleration of the car.** The units are arbitrary, and have no real value, the only thing that matters is the relative differences, which are within ~10%. Even though this chart is for mass, the inverse is the acceleration. The higher the mass, the lower the acceleration, and it is proportional. All your stats, then, can be derived from this one chart.

[image: Octane]
Mass: 10.242

[image: Marauder]
Mass: 10.856

[image: Zippy]
Mass: 10.298

[image: Renegade]
Mass: 10.943

[image: Aftershock]
Mass: 10.695

[image: Backfire]
Mass: 10.392

[image: Scarab]
Mass: 9.751